# Compare two different servers - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are planning to migrate a SQL server instance from machine X (on premises) to machine Y (Cloud).

The question: "can we guarantee the performance of the SQL server in the Cloud" came to me. So I thought it over for a while and came with the following scenario:

- make backup of database on machine X
- start profiler (via tsql) to record all activity -> trace to file
- restore database on machine Y
- start two profilers on machine Y, one for the replay and one for the timings

Is this a correct way to compare the performance of two database servers?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878183.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith well that's another - more sophisticated - way of testing, thnx